# sql2o - select query removing trailing spaces from VARCHAR coulmn

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql2o

using sql2o (https://github.com/aaberg/sql2o)

when selecting a VARCHAR column that has trailing spaces (for example `"some value    "`) the return value is `"some value"`

when selecting from mysql cli the result contains the trailing spaces

cant find any documentation how to prevent this from happening

- table:

```
CREATE TABLE names
(
    name     VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (experiment_key, metric_name)
);
```

- code example:

```
 Sql2o sql2o;

        String name = "some name with trailing space    ";
        try (Connection con = sql2o.open()) {
            con.createQuery("INSERT INTO names (name) VALUES(:name)")
                    .addParameter("name", name)
                    .executeUpdate();
        }        


        String nameFromDB; 
        try (Connection con = sql2o.open()) {
            nameFromDB =  con.createQuery("select name from names")
                    .executeAndFetchFirst(String.class);
        }

        if (!nameFromDB.equals(name)){
            throw new RuntimeException("where did the trailing spaces go ??? :( ");
        }
```

Comment: That `INSERT` query doesnt look like it would actually work. It should probably be `INSERT INTO names (name) VALUES(:name)`.

Comment: this is just an example to simplify that , ill update

Comment: What makes you think it's sql2o removing the trailing spaces, and not the database you're connected to?

Comment: from mysql cli running the query the result has trailing spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I found your answer in Sql2o.

I believe by using `String.class`, it is using the StringConverter class to convert your query output into a string. At the very bottom of the StringConverter class is this line:

```
return val.toString().trim();
```

Found [here](https://github.com/aaberg/sql2o/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/sql2o/converters/StringConverter.java)

Comment: do you think i can add a custom convertor that will replace this ? why will they trim in the end ?

Comment: ended up Implementing a custom converters and removing the trim